# how to run a single instance of teamcity build across all agents

Tags: teamcity

We have a teamcity set-up on with multiple agents. There is one particular build which uses some underlying resources and services of a particular environment. ( say uat)

We want that this build should not run n parallel to avoid resource contention. i.e. only a single running build at a time. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: This build which uses underlying resources cannot run while any other builds from any project are running or only a build of the same type?

Answer (score 2):

Under the project, setup a [shared resource](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/shared-resources.html):

[image: TeamCity shared resource]

Then under the build configurations you don't wish to be able to run in parallel add a build feature and select the resource you just created and "Write Lock":

[image: TeamCity shared resource build feature]

This will mean any extra builds triggered will stay in the build queue and will not be allowed to run concurrently.